# How to empty a table between two dates or id, with phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I would like to empty partly a table by using phpMyAdmin.

I know how to empty it totally.

But what would be the SQL request to empty a table:

- between two dates
- or between two id

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from exampleTable where id between 40000 and 50000
```

How to run SQL Statements in phpMyAdmin: http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin_mysql_query.htm